# How do a create an iPhoto Smart Album of ANY of the names X, Y or Z but only for the year 2013

Tags: photos.app, smart-folders

I'm trying to create a smart album that has "face is" with each member of my family the date range is a given year. In other words I'm trying to create a "yearly" smart album of just my immediate family members. I have used:

```
Face is Me
Face is Daughter
Face is Wife
```

with the ANY option selected.

But then when I add the date range line of *1/1/2013* to *12/31/2013* I get all pictures in 2013 and I just want the ones with faces.

Any ideas? In math I'm looking for (`x` or `y`or `z`) AND (`date` = `this year`) and I'm getting `x` or `y` or `z` OR `date` = `this year`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with iPhoto smart albums because you can't combine a conjunction with a disjunction in the same smart folder.  This would work, in a convoluted way, if iPhoto let you use a smart folder as an input, but unfortunately it doesn't (i.e., Album is MY_SMART_XYZ_ALBUM AND date is 2013).  iTunes can do this, but apparently not iPhoto.  Theoretically, it's possible to create "dumb" albums with smart contents in Automator, though.  It should also be possible to filter a conjunctive set of elements with a subsequent disjunctive criterion.  But I'm not sure how fast this would perform.

Answer (score 0):

... you can but it's a bit manual...

Use the "Or" statement to get all your family members into one smart album.

Select every photo and add the Keyword "Family".

New Smart album for Keyword Family and Date between = x & y.

Only problem is when new photos are added you'll need to update your Family Smart album's Keywords.  (Easy enough though to do though).

Comment: Instead of adding a keyword, you can keep the first smart album (name it Family) and create the second one with 'belongs to Family album' AND 'date between 1/1/13 and 12/31/13'

Comment: Yeah.. that would work.. nice one.